# Django postgresql adminer import sql file syntax error

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Firstly I exported the database in sql file and without changing anything, I tried to import same sql file to empty postgresql database using adminer.
But I get some errors and don't know what is the problem

**VERSION:** postgres:14.6

**ERROR IS LIKE THAT :**

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."auth_group" (
    "id" integer DEFAULT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "name" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "auth_group_name_key" UNIQUE ("name"),
    CONSTRAINT "auth_group_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false)
```

```
Error in query (7): ERROR: syntax error at or near "BY"
LINE 2: "id" integer DEFAULT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NO...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using postgres 14.6

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) the correct syntax is:

```
id" integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
```

The `DEFAULT` after `integer` is wrong.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/bk2MSKQz)

Comment: But when exporting from Adminer it gives the sql file with errors how it can be possible?
I would like to know the reason.

Comment: @Alasgar: well, whatever tool you are using apparently doesn't know how to treat identity columns. Use `pg_dump` then you shouldn't have any problems.